# PFUser/PFInstallaion saveEventually - Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am using `PFUser` and `PFInstallation` with the `saveEventually` method. However, when I call the method I get an error that reads:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Any idea what Xcode is asking for? Do I need to import any special header files? Here is my code:

```
PFUser.currentUser().saveEventually()

installation.saveEventually()
```

Comment: are you using local datastore? if not PFUser.currentUser() will return nil if user is not logged it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to import `BFTask.h` in my bridging header.

```
#import <Bolts/BFTask.h>
```